# Push Notification works only once

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

The push notification only works when the app is in background ,But it didn't work when i removed it from background also when it returned to background , i didn't receive any push notifications. I had to delete the app and download it again from testflight to be able to receive push notifications.

here's the code

```
    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

#if !TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
   //Do stuff that you would do if the application was not active

    NSLog(@"remote notification: %@",[userInfo description]);
    NSDictionary *apsInfo = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];
    NSLog(@"Aps Info : %@",apsInfo);


    NSString *alert = [apsInfo objectForKey:@"alert"];
    NSLog(@"Received Push Alert: %@", alert);

    NSString *sound = [apsInfo objectForKey:@"sound"];
    NSLog(@"Received Push Sound: %@", sound);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);

    NSString *badge = [apsInfo objectForKey:@"badge"];
    NSLog(@"Received Push Badge: %@", badge);
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[apsInfo objectForKey:@"badge"] integerValue];


#endif
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))completionHandler

{
    NSInteger pushCode = [userInfo[@"pushCode"] integerValue];
    NSLog(@"Silent Push Code Notification: %i", pushCode);
    NSDictionary *aps = userInfo[@"aps"];
    NSString *typeID = userInfo[@"type_id"];

    NSString *alertMessage = aps[@"alert"];
    NSLog(@"Type ID %@",typeID);

    NSArray * array =[typeID componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

    NSLog(@"Item %@,Item2 %@",[array objectAtIndex:0],[array objectAtIndex:1]);
    [self typeID:[array objectAtIndex:0] userID:[array objectAtIndex:1] message:alertMessage];
    NSLog(@"apss%@,alert%@,%@",aps,alertMessage,userInfo);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the method:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))completionHandler 
{
}
```

you should "catch" the notifications which arrive in background with this method:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
}
```

the *fetchCompletionHandler* method is designed for receiving "silent" push messages, which gets called prior to *didReceiveRemoteNotification*, if implemented.